# Two level Flask server

Tags: python, flask, jwt

I have a requirement to have a two level flask server - one external and one internal. The external server is exposed to outer world, authenticates a user, generates a JWT and will forward the requests to the inner server.

The internal server accepts requests only from the outer server and execute the requests with valid JWT.

How could this be achieved? I want how to technically design this kind of application.

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it can be done, of course. On the other hand, I've never seen anyone use flask for the "outer" server. That does not seem to be the optimal solution.

Comment: Use a text editor. Write code for the internal server first.

Comment: By outer server I mean the one that interacts with the user interface or the one that is exposed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty common-- lets take a cloud server setup that has private networking (e.g. Amazon, but they all do generally).  You could create two servers, and give them a private IP address, and also give the external server a public IP address.

Your public one can talk to the private one via it's private ip/hostname, but it won't be accessible from anyone else externally. [AWS Documentation on Private IPs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-instance-addressing.html#concepts-private-addresses)

Alternatively, using just one server you could serve the 'internal' instance on `127.0.0.1:5000` and so the 'external' server, also hosted on the server, but served on `0.0.0.0:80` would be able to talk to it via `127.0.0.1:5000` but would be unroutable from the outside world, since `127.0.0.1` always resolves to your own machine/device.

*Or* you could lean on firewall rules to filter out anything not from the 'external' server that was directed to the 'internal' one-- but I think there's less scope for messing things up if it's simply not possible to route to it from an outside address